# TypeError: Cannot read property of Selector-Matcher

Tags: asp.net, angular, webpack

I am working on an Angular2 & ASP.NET Core project with webpack and I suddenly get an error. I didn't have this error yesterday and I didn't make any changes today. Does anyone have an idea what the problem is?

Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'SelectorMatcher' of undefined
at Object. (C:\Users\john\Desktop\WORKSHOP...\node_modules\angular2-platform-node__private_imports__.js:21:54)

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "Angular2Workshop",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A simple application with an Angular 2 app and a Asp.Net Core Backend",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/karma start",
    "postinstall": "typings install && npm uninstall selenium-webdriver"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.38",
    "angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.10",
    "angular2-universal": "~2.0.10",
    "angular2-universal-polyfills": "~2.0.10",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^1.0.6",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.11",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "es7-reflect-metadata": "^1.4.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "preboot": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.5.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.2",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "http-server": "^0.8.5",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "^0.1.3",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.3",
    "karma": "^0.13.15",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.6",
    "karma-webpack": "1.7.0",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.18",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.1",
    "protractor": "^3.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "ts-helper": "0.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "tsconfig-lint": "^0.4.3",
    "tslint": "^3.2.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "typedoc": "^0.3.12",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3",
    "typings": "^1.4.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.12.1",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.4"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config

```
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var merge = require('webpack-merge');
var allFilenamesExceptJavaScript = /\.(?!js(\?|$))([^.]+(\?|$))/;

// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
var sharedConfig = {
    resolve: { extensions: [ '', '.js', '.ts' ] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts', query: { silent: true } },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'to-string!css' },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url', query: { limit: 25000 } }
        ]
    }
};

// Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
var clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/dist') },
    devtool: isDevBuild ? 'inline-source-map' : null,
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});

// Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
var serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.ts' },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
    },
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    externals: [nodeExternals({ whitelist: [allFilenamesExceptJavaScript] })] // Don't bundle .js files from node_modules
});

module.exports = [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use  2.0.0 version

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0"
```

I think it is some issue with Angular2.1.1

https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/406

Comment: Link is dead. You can follow this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41396055/upgrading-from-angular-2-0-0-to-2-4-0-cannot-read-property-selectormatcher